# Retrieve list of table names

Tags: java, rethinkdb, reql

I want to get the list of tables in a database.

[The documentation of the `tableList` command](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/table_list/) says this method returns a list of strings, but that is not exactly the case. It actually returns a `TableList` object.

And when I run..

```java
r.db("test").tableList().run(conn);
```

I get a `Result<Object>` object as result with one entry that is really an `ArrayList` with all table names I want.

So, is this actually how this is supposed to work now:

```java
Connection connection = r.connection().hostname(DEFAULT_HOSTNAME).port(DEFAULT_PORT).connect();

Object tableListObject = r.db(DEFAULT_DB_NAME).tableList().run(connection).single();

if (tableListObject instanceof Collection) {
    List<?> tableList = new ArrayList<>((Collection<?>) tableListObject);

    for(Object tableName : tableList) {
        System.out.println(tableName);
    }
}
```

Seems rather complicated to me, is there an official/better way to do this?

I am using the RethinkDB Java driver version 2.4.4.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Are you aware that your link is sending me to this very question? .. 

Comment: My apologies @Johannes, I wasn't aware of that and now I can't find the link intended. :( I believe I originally got it from this [ReThinkDB web page](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/table_list/) but can seem to dig it up any more. There were few answers within the SO thread which may of helped. Again, my apologies.

Comment: @DevilsHnd No worries.. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `run()` method which allows you to specify the class of the returned results - in this case an array of strings:

```
Connection conn = r.connection().hostname("localhost").port(32769).connect();
List<?> tables = r.db("test").tableList().run(conn, ArrayList.class).first();
if (tables != null) {
    tables.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

For me, this prints the following in my test DB:

```
movies
tv_shows
```

Updated to use `List<?>` as suggested by @Johannes.

Comment: That's much better.. maybe even use `List<?> tables = ...` to avoid the unchecked cast warning.

Comment: Yes - thank you for pointing that out. I had somehow managed to disable that warning check in my IDE. I would never have noticed...